Purpose of visit (specifically, the type of business visit) for a short research visit in France
I am a PhD student visiting France for a short (< 14 days) research visit to one of the universities. I believe I require a short stay visa for business purposes. On the visa application portal, which specialization (under the business visit section) do I have to select? The relevant options are:

Business trip
Cultural, artistic, scientific, and sports events
Scientist/researcher

I believe the third option is the most relevant, but it requires “Convention d’accueil” which I do not have (see https://www.service-public.fr/particuliers/vosdroits/R58896?lang=en). I do have an invitation letter from the Professor who is hosting me. So, my question is the following:
Does a signed invitation letter from the Professor suffice for the third item in the above list? If not, do I have to choose another option from the list? If so, which one?

Did you ask the host university if they can provide the hosting agreement?

I have not. I have a visa appointment scheduled pretty soon. I have selected the third option, and the host university will not be able to furnish the "Convention d'Accueil" soon enough, I believe. However, I plan to fill out another application to take with me to the appointment, just in case. Hence the question.

In principle, it shouldn't matter, those are not hard and fast categories with specific requirements. There is however a risk the consular officer would insist on this “convention d'accueil”, even if you check another box. Either way, they will see you are a scientist visiting a university and proceed accordingly.

If you don't have a hosting agreement, you should be careful to justify your visit as a visit and not including any actual research "work" that will be done only after you are back to your home institution ;-).

Right, that makes sense. Thank you!
